# iPhone SDK Accessing what a user is typing

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there a way to see what a user is typing in any application while on their iPhone, and then do something based on what they have typed. For example, if a user is typing a text message, is there a way to see what he's typing and hyperlink a word, or display a notification?

Let me know if you require further clarification.

**EDIT:**

The text monitoring will be happening on different applications; I want to be able to track all typed text, so if the user is typing a note or a text message, I want to be able to track that.

Comment: If the iPhone is not jailbroken, impossible. Never heard of a way even if jailbroken

Comment: Consult the API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the views associated with text entry have [delegate methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html), but it does not appear that they will send notifications at the granularity of every character. Of course, you could make your own view and do whatever you want. It's difficult to answer your question without code, but the answer appears to be "yes, but not easily".

Answer (score 0):

Experiment with:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

You'll need to implement UITextFieldDelegate & set the textField's delegate to whatever (e.g.) viewController you're using so you get the message when any change is made to the textField.

I'm assuming you mean within the app that you're coding, & not any other app which may be running - that would be impossible & probably not desirable!

Comment: ok but I want to monitor text being written in other applications...for example if they are typing a text message, or if they are typing a note